# BsDatepicker doesn't show up in Children Components (ngx-bootstrap)

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I'm working with **Angular 5** and I want to use `ngx-bootstrap` `bsDatepicker` module. I followed steps from https://ngx-universal.herokuapp.com/datepicker but datepicker doesn't show up. I just get console warning message. I don't get any error message

> warn-once.js:10
>
> BsDatepickerModule is under development,
>
> BREAKING CHANGES are possible,
>
> PLEASE, read changelog

Datepicker element also not rendered

[image]

my `app.module.ts`

```
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
...
imports: [
   ... ,
   BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
   ... ,
],
```

my `custom.component.html`

```
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Datepicker" bsDatepicker formControlName="date" />
  </div>
```

I also added CDN link of `bsDatepicker` css file to my `index.html`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css">
```

Versions of ngx-bootstrap, Angular, and Bootstrap:

- ngx-bootstrap: ^2.0.2
- Angular: 5.2.7
- Bootstrap: 3.3.7

Build system:

- Angular CLI: 1.7.2
- webpack: 3.11.0
- typescript: 2.4.2

Comment: datepicker appends to the end of the body, perhaps you have some z-index conflicts?

Comment: @IlyaSurmay No, I don't have any style problem. If this element rendered, why I can't inspect it ? :(

Comment: have you looked at the bottom of `body` after clicking on that input? if datepicker isn't there, then please create a reproduction of this issue via plunkr/stackblitz/github repo

Comment: Yes, I did. I just want to share problem with stackoverflow, I thought maybe I have a mistake. Thanks for reply, man. I'll add issue about this. :)

Comment: same problem for me. i use bootstrap 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find a solution.

Bug or Problem is : I added `BsDatepickerModule.forRoot()` to my `app.module.ts` but It works on `app.compontent.html`. I can't use it in my Children Components which loaded with `lazyLoading`, `BsDatepickerModule.forRoot()` doesn't work globally for all components. I don't know what`s wrong.

***Temporary solution*** :

I add `BsDatepickerModule.forRoot()` to my children components which I want to use datepicker in it. This solves my problem for now.

Comment: i took your solution from here --    https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/3883   --  You were more precise there.  you need to add the import and the  - imports: [BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),...] in the same module that declare the component

Comment: @yehonatanyehezkel yeah this solution is mine )) You can see on github )) i also opened issue on github after wrote here and added solution before owner want to close the issue.

Comment: @rufatZZ When you `add BsDatepickerModule.forRoot()` to your child components, how exactly are you doing that? I need the workaround because I have the same problem. I've posted a new issue with a working example demonstrating it, so hopefully they will identify the problem and fix it: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/4608

Comment: @Mathachew i add `BsDatepickerModule.forRoot()` to my `child.module.ts` file,  if i wanted to use this modal in my child component, i really have no other idea for solve that problem :(  Its really sad, I also posted issue but they closed and didn't answer :(

Comment: @rufatZZ I was able to finally get it working in `shared.module.ts` by having `BsDatepickerModule.forRoot()` in the imports array and `BsDatepickerModule` in the exports array. I only had it listed in the imports previously.

Answer (score 4):

There are two solutions to the problem. You should make this decision depending on your app's architecture. If you only have a smaller app with a few Child components, then just add `BsDatepickerModule.forRoot()` to the imports of the child component.  If you have a larger app, or one that will grow over time, then the best solution is to add the `BsDatepickerModule.forRoot()` to your imports and `BsDatepickerModule` in your exports of your **Shared Module**. If you don't have a **Shared Module** (which you should), then check [this](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules) and [this](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#shared-feature-module) out.

**Large App Solution(Best)**

```
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
imports: [
    .....
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    .....
  ],
exports: [
    .....
    BsDatepickerModule,
    .....
   ]
})
```

**Small App Solution(Good but not best)**

```
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
imports: [
    .....
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    .....
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Add style URL in .angular-cli.json file

```
"styles": ["../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css"],
```

#### Import module in app.module.ts

```
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

@NgModule({
imports: [
    .....
    CarouselModule.forRoot(),
    .....
  ]
})
```

#### Add Date control in .html file

```
<div  class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Datepicker" bsDatepicker formControlName="date" />
          </div>
```

it is working for me

Answer (score -1):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css">
```

I added the CDN link to the style sheet in `index.htm`. It is working fine.

Comment: @סטנליגרונן: It seems they were struggling to get the markup to display in the answer. I’ve updated the formatting to expose their suggestion. I can’t validate if this is a _correct_ answer to the original problem, but it’s at least not as nonsensical as it initially appeared.